# Entity Framework parse decimal single fields into list<decimal> with select command

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list response from EF query and Entity class hade decimal price property.
What ı want to do is ı want to .Select() into List this list response and take these every single decimal price value into the listofdecimal property of Entity2.

For ex I have 3 records of list like;

```
updateUser=1
price =2.2

updateUser=1
price =3.2

updateUser=1
price =4.2
```

after select ı want to see only one Entity2 with;

```
updateUser=1
prices ={2.2,3.2,4.2}
```

thx in advance for advices.

Comment: This is not really something the DB needs to do as it's just reshuffling objects and not aggregating, so something like `.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(e => e.updateUser).Select(g => new Entity2 { updateUser = g.Key, prices = g.Select(e => e.price).ToList() })` with plain LINQ to Objects would do.

Comment: What if ı got more than 2 field ? for ex updateUser, price and Name ?. I did .AsEnumerable().GroupBy(e => e.updateUser).Select(g => new Entity2 { updateUser = g.Key, Name = g.Select(e=>e.Name).FirstOrDefault(), prices = g.Select(e => e.price).ToList() }) but ı got Sequence has no elements' Exception @JeroenMostert